# Why the difference in send/receive fees on localbitcoins.com?

Tags: transaction-fees, localbitcoins

At least in https://localbitcoins.com/, the fees for sending and receiving Bitcoins (from/to outside localbitcoins, of course) differ by a factor of three, approximately. Currently:
0.08715 mBTC for sending, 0.26144 mBTC for receiving.

Is there some rationale for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specific to LocalBitcoins.

From the website,

> In order  to divide the costs of handling Bitcoin transactions in a
>   fair manner we are introducing deposit fees for incoming transactions.
>   At the same we will lower Bitcoin sending fees for all customers.
>
> Deposit fees will be larger than the new sending fees, generally we
>   expect it to be about 3x the amount of sending fees.

Thanks!

https://localbitcoins.com/blog/new-bitcoin-network-fee-model/